# Cant read xlsx file with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying read .xlsx file as dataframe. File itself has two worksheet but when I tried to read it returns empty worksheet. Even though I have specified the sheet_name, it returns there is not a worksheet named like you have provided.

I have used several methods but all returns [].
'''

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(filename="filename.xlsx",read_only = True, data_only = True)
print(workbook.sheetnames)
```

'''

'''

```
xl = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')
xl.sheet_names
```

'''

Comment: Do you *need* to read in Excel sheets dynamically, or is this an ad hoc task? If the latter, consider just exporting the sheet you need to .csv and reading it that way. Probably an obvious workaround, but it's easy to sometimes get stuck on a problem that doesn't necessarily need to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

With pandas:

[pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(
    io='filename.xlsx',
    sheet_name='your sheet name',
    engine='openpyxl'
)
```

With openpyxl:

[Read an existing workbook](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook) and
[Converting a worksheet to a Dataframe](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html#converting-a-worksheet-to-a-dataframe)

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
wb = load_workbook(
    filename='filename.xlsx',
    data_only=True
)
sheet_names = wb.sheetnames  # list available sheet names in workbook
ws = wb['your sheet name']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=ws)
```

Comment: Hi, I have already tried these ones but they did not work. Because both read_excel and load_workbook read like there is no worksheet or file is empty, But it does not. I have two worksheet with data inside the xlsx file

Answer (score 0):

If you need list of sheet names:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('filename.xlsx')
xl.sheet_names

# to read from specific sheet
xl.parse(sheetname)
```

If you know the sheet name just use:

`pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name='sheetname')`

Comment: Not working and I have tried with index it returns like 'Worksheet index 0 is invalid, 0 worksheets found'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I found the problem. It was because of excel.